# Best practice of async call on flutter?

Tags: flutter

I don't want the async call fire every time when the widget rebuild.
So, I call the async function in initState.

1. call async in initState

   ```
   @override
   void initState() {
     someAsyncCall().then((result) {
       setState() {
        _result = result;
       }
     });
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     if (_result == null) {
       reutrn new Container();
     }

     return new SomeWidget();
   }
   ```
2. use FutureBuilder

   ```
   @override
   void initState() {
     _future = someAsyncCall();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return new FutureBuilder(
       future: _future,
       builder: // do something
     );
   }
   ```

Is there any side effect or bad practice on both solution?

---

I modify the demo app from flutter to explain why I call the async in initSate.
1. open app, print main
2. push screen to test, print test, main
3. pop test, print main

If I call async function in build, it calls three times.
What I want is, I need the async function call once, unless the main dispose / pop.
According to the answer from Rémi Rousselet, call async in initState is kind of a problem or wrong.
So, how can I make sure the async function call once?

```
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("build main");
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return new Test();
              }));
            }),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

 class Test extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     print("build Test");
     return new Scaffold(
       body:
       new FlatButton(onPressed: () {
         Navigator.pop(context);
       }, child: new Text("back"))
     );
   }

 }
```

Do I need to do something like

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  if (!mounted) {
    print("build main");
    // aysnc function call here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While slightly more verbose, the `FutureBuilder` definitely is the way to go.

Calling async function within the initState and then doing a `setState` when they finish has a few problems. Most of the time while doing this, you won't bother about error catching or handling the loading time.

Bear in mind that Flutter expects `initState` to be synchronous. So while dart doesn't prevent you from doing async calls into sync functions, flutter will most likely think your widget is ready when it's not.

Comment: If call async function in initState is not encouraging or wrong, that means I need to call those function in build? Or store the future in initState is acceptable(not call  then)? It gives a heavy loading to server API. Also, the scroller offset will be reset when I press back button because of the async call fire again.

Comment: Don't confuse `initState`, `createState` and `build`; they are not *all* called every time the widget tree changes. `createState` is called to create the State and `initState` is one-time initialization, so these will only be called once. Build is called very time the widget or parent widget state changes from a call to `setState`. See the docs for the lifecycle details: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Comment: I have updated the question after reading this doc. Not sure the usage is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the first style as I can control what happens whilst waiting. It depends on what you want from your app, and I prefer a clear "loading" message rather than not knowing if it is stuck or loading.

And speaking of side effects, you can see what they said about [FutureBuilder](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

> A side-effect of this is that providing a new but already-completed future to a FutureBuilder will result in a single frame in the ConnectionState.waiting state. This is because there is no way to synchronously determine that a Future has already completed.